# Aspel dictionaries for Jazzy libraires in Java

Tags: java, swing, spell-checking, jtextarea, aspell

I want to implement spell check into J2SE desktop application. To do this i use Jazzy (http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/). How to import and use aspel's dictionaries (from Aspel Dictionaries ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html), because I have only one dictionary - English, but I want more: French and Polish.

Answer (score 1):

Jazzy uses a simple text file with one word a line, and a blank line in between - such as

> Alaska
>
> Alaska's
>
> Albania
>
> Albania's

You'll have to either:

- Convert the aspel dictionaries to that format (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/137957/how-to-convert-aspell-dictionary-to-simple-list-of-words));
- Implement/find a `java.io.Reader` that reads from the aspel format and returns a word each call to `readLine()`, so you can use `new SpellDictionaryHashMap(Reader yourAspelReader);`

Comment: I agree, but when I convert Polish dict to this format I will have 49MB dictionary. Aspell's pl.cwl has only 2MB.

Comment: @PiotrSobolewski, you can use `SpellDictionaryDisk` if you don't want the whole file loaded in-memory. Of course, it comes with some additional latency.

Comment: do you have any example of using SpellDictionaryDisk?

Comment: @PiotrSobolewski, `SpellDictionaryDisk` implements `SpellDictionary` - so you shouldn't need to change any of your existing code. Just load it with `new SpellDictionaryDisk(File base, File phonetic, boolean block)`. You can take a look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jazzy/jazzy/0.5.2-rtext-1.4.1/com/swabunga/spell/engine/SpellDictionaryDisk.java), might clarify.

Comment: I do something wrong;/ I have file named "words". This file contains my dictionary (1 word per 1 line). When I try to run sample app (here is a code: http://pastie.org/4030843) i also has got:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.swabunga.spell.engine.SpellDictionaryDisk.newDictionaryFiles(Unknown Source)

What I did wrong?

Comment: @PiotrSobolewski, it's been some time since I last used it, but your code seems fine (considering your arguments are correct). You should download the source for Jazzy and debug it, it's probably something simple.

Comment: I have taken this code from Jazzy examples, but line with new SpellDictionaryDisk(File base, File phonetic, boolean block) was commented. In example author used new SpellDictionaryHashMap(dictFile, phonetFile). You could look at this example there: [link](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/jazzy/src/com/swabunga/spell/examples/JTextComponentSpellCheckExample.java.shtml)

Comment: @PiotrSobolewski, that doesn't look like an "official" example... anyway, I've tried it and it worked fine with the default english dictionary (placed on the `dict/english.0/words` folder - it created the words DB on `dict/english.0/db`). Maybe it's something with your dict file?

Comment: Probably it is. I will check it tomorrow and I will let you know.